# Keepalive для TCP сокета на C для iOS & android

Tags: c, ios, сокет, macos, tcp

Дано:

- мобильный клиент с сетевой частью на С
- сервер
- TCP соединение

Хочу улучшить:

- Когда сервер молча закрывает TCP сокет, приложение должно об этом узнать за разумное время (около минуты)

Возникшая проблема:

хотел сделать
setsockopt( socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &true, sizeof(int) )
Но на iOS нет настроек TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, TCP_KEEPCNT

Не может же быть такого, что нельзя настроить keepalive на iOS?? Возможно я подхожу к решению не с той стороны?)

Comment: что значит «cервер молча закрывает TCP сокет»? при корректном закрытии соединения клиент должен уведомляться и получать ошибку при попытке чтения из сокета. Иное возможно только в случае смерти сервера или обрыва соединения. Keepalive нужен именно в этих случаях, но устанавливают его обычно только со стороны сервера и интервалы составляют часы, а на стороне клиента обходятся другими таймаутами.

Comment: данная задача обычно решается пингами. То есть, сервер и клиент шлют друг-дружке маленькие сообщения известного содержания с известными периодами. Отсутствие сообщения по истечению времени - разрыв.

Comment: Сервер - плохо работающая железяка, там нет полноценной ОС, сокет закрывается без уведомления. К сожалению к коду этой железяки у меня доступа нет, я могу менять только код клиента (

Comment: да, iOS сделана для непонятно кого, там все работает странно. Но.. всегда можно поменять на нормальный телефон:) Если сервер не поддерживает пингов, можно поискать что то подходящее - какой то дешевый запрос, который можно дергать чуть чаще, чем обычно. При этом, его может дергать только один, выделенный клиент, а всем остальным рассылать пуши.